# Calculating Cosine Similarity between two graph nodes with different number of vectors

Tags: math, vector, machine-learning, nlp

I'm implementing the paper titled "[Efficient Graph-Based Semi-Supervised Learning of Structured Tagging Models](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.175.4079&rep=rep1&type=pdf)" as part of my research.

As part of graph construction procedure which is the Section 3 of the paper, I need to define some kind of similarity measure to calculate edge weight for each edge connecting a pair of nodes. According to the paper, I have to create a PMI (Pointwise Mutual Information) vector for this purpose. What I have to do is to calculate PMIs for features occurring on each token.

Each n-gram is named "type" and each of its occurrences is named "token" in this paper.

As an example if we take x2-x3-x4 to be our current Type which occurs in two contexts x1-x2-x3-x4-x5 and x6-x2-x3-x4-x7 I have to compute a set of features relating to the type x2-x3-x4. But somehow this procedure seems complex and unclear. This is what I got:

- I should calculate PMI's for each feature on every Token. Which results in a vector of PMIs for each token and the final result would be an array of PMI vectors for the current Type. The array size will be equal to the count of tokens of a given type. Now as a final step I should measure similarity of different nodes. But the problem is that the resulting vector array of each type has a different size, so I can not compare these arrays with each other.

So, what is the solution? Did I made a mistake here?